# Poor man's serial sniffer: reading Serial.print logs of an Arduino esp32 dev kit from another

Tags: serial, esp32

(I use ESP32 dev kits with Arduino api.)

My dev kit 1 is running my firmware; and I want to measure the current it draws, therefore I don't like to plug the USB in.

As I need to read the logs from the dev kit 1, I want to plug another dev kit that collects the log from the first through the UART.

The dev kit 1 firmware is as it is, but on the dev kit 2, I wrote such a thing:

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Hardware.h>

HardwareSerial Reader();

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Reader.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17); 

}

void loop() {
    while(Reader.available()) { 
        Serial.print(Reader.read());
    }
}
```

The wiring is as follows:

| Dev kit 1 | Wiring | Dev kit 2 (sniffer) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TXD | <=> | RXD (16) |
| RXD | <=> | TXD (17) |
| GND | <=> | GND |

But this doesn't work, that is I can't see anything on the dev kit 2 serial on my computer.
Any idea?

[UPDATE] As suggested by @juraj, I simply wire TX to TX, RX to RX and GND to GND and removed the Serial.begin(115200) from the firmware running on dev kit 1.
Dev kit 2 firmware is as simple as:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Serial.printf("Serial2 logger RX (%d)<=>TX & TX(%d)<=>RX @ 115200 bauds", RX, TX); Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned lastHeartbeat = 0;

  const unsigned now =millis();
  if (now-lastHeartbeat > 4000) {
    lastHeartbeat = now;
    Serial.println("Heartbeat");
  }
}
```

Note that on dev kit 1, I commented out the line `Serial.begin(115200)`.

No kit 1 logs appears on my computer.

The wiring of this setup:

[image]

Comment: `But this doesn't work` is not a useful description of any problem ... what were you expecting to happen? ... what actually happens?

Comment: As you just want to forward the serial data, don't use `print()` but `write()` in your sketch. Otherwise `print()` will interpret the data before sending and you just want to forward the raw data. With TXD and RXD I guess you mean (depending on the notation) TX0 and RX0 (or U0_TXD and U0_RXD), so GPIO1 and GPIO3 on the firmware board?

Comment: yep, TXD is TX0 is GPIO1 and RXD is RX0 is GPIO3. I could craft a macro to transform the prints in write, but then it should be easier to hook an ISR and write to the pins myself. What do you think?

Comment: `Serial.write(Reader.read());`

Comment: if you just wire RX to RX and TX to TX the CH340 on the dev board will read it directly and send to USB. upload Blink or any other sketch without Serial.begin into the esp32

Comment: `HardwareSerial Reader();` should be `HardwareSerial Reader;`

Comment: @juraj I tried this but nothing is received. The USB logger do not show any logs. I update the question with a simple board wiring photo, just in case I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work.

### The final wiring:

| Kit 1 | kit 2 |
| --- | --- |
| The firmware to spy | The firmare that spys |
| RXD | 17 |
| TXD | 16 |
| GND | GND |

### The spying firmware uses Serial2

```
#define USE_READER true


#if USE_READER
#define USE_SERIAL2 true

#if USE_SERIAL2
    #define TX 17
    #define RX 16
    #define Reader Serial2
#else
    #include "SoftwareSerial.h"
    #define TX 12
    #define RX 13
    SoftwareSerial Reader;
#endif
#endif

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

#if USE_READER
  Serial.printf("Serial logger RX (%d)<=>TX & TX(%d)<=>RX @ 115200 bauds", RX, TX); Serial.println();

  #if USE_SERIAL2
  Reader.begin(115200);
  #else
  Reader.begin(115200, SWSERIAL_8N1, RX, TX, false);
  #endif
  #endif
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned lastHeartbeat = 0;

  const unsigned now =millis();
  if (now-lastHeartbeat > 4000) {
    lastHeartbeat = now;
    Serial.println("Heartbeat");
  }

  #if USE_READER
  if (Reader.available()) {
    
    Serial.write(Reader.read());  
  }
  else {
    #endif
    
    //Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
    
    #if USE_READER
  }
  #endif
}
```

### The spied firmware

You leave it as it is. Don't remove `Serial.begin(115200);`.

### The breadboard photo:

[image]